# add HTML ID via DOM javascript manpulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible to add an HTML ID via the browser console using DOM Manipulation?

For example, suppose I am dealing with the following element:

```
<div class="elementClass">
```

I can fetch via DOM with something like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("elementClass");
```

However, is it possible to add an attribute via this type of method? If I inspect the element with chrome I can do it manually, but I am wondering if it's possible to inject that ID via JavaScript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("elementClass")[0].setAttribute("id", "some ID");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can modify attributes of an object (HTMLElement) via javascript

getElementsByclassName returns an array, simply iterate through the list and set the attributes you wish.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("elementClass");
for(var I = 0; I < elements.length; I++)
    element[I].id = "element" + I;
```

Then you could access any of those elements with that class via

```
 var element = document.getElementById("element" + 0);  //Gets First Element
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('elementClass')[0].id = 'someID';
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('elementClass')[0].setAttribute('id', 'someID');
```

Just know that if you grab elements using `getElementsByClassName` then it will return an array of elements (assuming any elements with the matching class exist) so modifying the array won't give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

`setAttribute()` method on the `DOM element` should work just fine.

**HTML**

```
<div class="elementClass">
  This is the content of elementClass
</div>

<button onclick="buttonClicked()">Click to add attribute id red to elementClass</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function buttonClicked(){
 document.getElementsByClassName("elementClass")[0].setAttribute("id", "red");
}
```

**CSS**

```
#red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[PLAYGROUND](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/BlyKw)

**Note** that manipulating the `class attribute` causes the browser to [reflow](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/), therefore it is worth mentioning to use `setAttribute()` wisely to not cause performance issue.